# UIAlertAction closure is not being called when presenting Controller is modal

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` which is embedeed in `UINavigationController` which is being presented modally over my application's `keyWindow.rootViewController`. When I present `UIAlertController` in any screen of the presented navigation controller, the alert controller is correctly displayed but the closures for any of the `UIAlertAction` are not being called after being pressed.

I am displaying the same alert controller with the same code in view controllers belonging to the main navigation controller of my app and the closures are called properly.

The code for presenting the alert is very simple, here's the snippet:

```
    // Creating Alert
func createAlert() -> UIAlertController {
           let actions: [UIAlertAction] = [
                    UIAlertAction(title: "Something", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                        self.setOriginalQueue(with: items, description: description, identifier: identifier)
                        self.setQueue()
                    }),
                    UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
                        normal()
                    })
                ]

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet, actions: actions)

    return alert
}

    // In ViewController
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

So the question is, why are the closures not being called?

Comment: Why you calling return alert?

Comment: because u did not call ur alert . Correction :  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(createAlert(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

Answer (score 1):

**UIAlertController** does not contain four types argument. See the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller).

Once you fixed that, the rest will be automatically fixed like below.

For everyone's convenience I'll put the whole Modal view controller class source here.

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.present(createAlert(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func createAlert() -> UIAlertController {

        let actions: [UIAlertAction] = [
                        UIAlertAction(title: "Something", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                            print("Something")
                        }),
                        UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
                            print("Cancel")
                        })
                    ]
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        for action in actions {
            alert.addAction(action)
        }

        return alert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line is wrong.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "message" , preferredStyle: .actionSheet, actions: actions)
```

You must be get error like that

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Change it like that:

```
return UIAlertController(title: YourTitle, message: YourMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
```

So it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass name of the method when you are presenting alert

```
self.present(createAlert(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```